# Laravel - amazon subdomain hosting issue

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

1. I am creating 2 sub-domains like gateway.domain.com and hp.domain.com
2. I have installed 2 separate projects name gateway and HP in my local machine,
3. I upload gateway to gateway.domain.com
4. It’s working fine.
5. I upload hp to hp.domain.com
6. But I got a issue like

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class RFID4U_HP\Http\Kernel does not exist' in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/Gateway/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:738 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/Gateway/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(738): ReflectionClass->__construct('RFID4U_HP\Http...') #1 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/Gateway/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(633): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('RFID4U_HP\Http...', Array) #2 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/Gateway/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('RFID4U_HP\Http...', Array) #3 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/Gateway/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('RFID4U_HP\Http...', Array) #4 /var/www/clients/client1/ in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/Gateway/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 738

Also hp will going to read gateway fw path, I am not able to understand why this happen. In my lcl it’s working fine.

Some time it will reverse functioning hp working gateway will find the path in hp folder.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class RFID4U_GW\Http\Kernel does not exist' in 
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/hp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:738 Stack trace: #0 
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/hp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(738): ReflectionClass->__construct('RFID4U_GW\Http...') #1 
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/hp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(633): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('RFID4U_GW\Http...', Array) #2 
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/hp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('RFID4U_GW\Http...', Array) #3 
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/hp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('RFID4U_GW\Http...', Array) #4 
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/hp/ve in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/subdomains/hp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line

Comment: Some times reverse hp working gateway not working , gateway will find hp file path. Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class RFID4U_GW\Http\Kernel does not exist' in